# Fragment not showing right away in TabLayout but only when swiping back to it

Tags: java, android

Feel free to point me to places where this question was eventually answered and solved if this is a duplicate, I looked for possible clones but I didn't see anything that was similar, since what I saw concerns fragments not showing at all while I only don't see it at first but it does load when I swipe back to it.

Anyway, my problem is I have this events app I am coding with Firebase where associations can post events and regular users can save the posted events in a list. Now my problem lies in the associations home screen, where I set up (or at least I tried) a tab layout where the posting association can either see a tab with a form where he can create an event or a tab that shows a list of all the event they published. Problem is that when I try to test the app, when I land on the association home activity, the creation form should pop up first, instead the fragment stays blank but finally appears once I swipe on the other tab and then back to the form tab. Do you have any solutions for this?

This is the Association Home Activity method that has the fragments layout

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_event);
 
 tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
 frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
 
 TabLayout.Tab createTab = tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.create_event);
 tabLayout.addTab(createTab);
 
 TabLayout.Tab listTab = tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.event_list);
 tabLayout.addTab(listTab);
 
 tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
         @Override
 public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
 Fragment fragment = null;
 switch(tab.getPosition()) {
 case 0:
 fragment = new EventCreationFragment();
 break;
 case 1:
 fragment = new EventListFragment();
 break;
             }
 FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
 assert fragment != null;
 ft.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
 ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
 ft.commit();
         }

         @Override
 public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
 
         }
 
         @Override
 public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
 
         }
     });
 }
```

And this is the fragment code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event_creation, container, false);

    title = view.findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
    description = view.findViewById(R.id.etDesc);
    address = view.findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
    date = view.findViewById(R.id.etDate);
    timeFrom = view.findViewById(R.id.etTimeFrom);
    timeTo = view.findViewById(R.id.etTimeTo);
    ticket = view.findViewById(R.id.etTicket);

    addImage = view.findViewById(R.id.btnLoadImage);
    preview = view.findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);

    cancel = view.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    createEvent = view.findViewById(R.id.btnCreateEvent);

    storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("pictures");
    eventRef = dbRef.child("Evento");

    date.setOnClickListener(this::selectDate);
    timeFrom.setOnClickListener(this::selectTimeFrom);
    timeTo.setOnClickListener(this::selectTimeTo);
    addImage.setOnClickListener(this::addImage);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(this::cancel);
    createEvent.setOnClickListener(this::createEvent);

    return view;
}
```

The whole Firebase part of it is fine, my problem is just that the fragment isn't created right away but only after I swipe back to it. Second fragment isn't coded yet so nothing will show up for now, I just want to display the expected one first for now.

Any kind of help is appreciated

Tried to create a Tab Layout with two fragment tabs, expected to see the first one when landing but nothing shows at first but only when swiping back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code responsible for showing/adding `Fragment`s is placed only inside `OnClickListener`, you aren't setting any `Fragment` on runtime start

introduce some common method for showing fragment

```
private void showFragmentAtPosition(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch(position) {
    case 0:
    fragment = new EventCreationFragment();
    break;
    case 1:
    fragment = new EventListFragment();
    break;
             }
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    assert fragment != null;
    ft.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.commit();
}
```

call `showFragmentAtPosition(tab.getPosition());` inside `onTabSelected`, but also in `onCreate` (with default `position = 0`?) only when `savedInstanceState` is `null` (means thats a really first start, not some recreation due to e.g. device rotation or phone call end)

Comment: i'm almost certain you heard the ultrasonic facepalm i just pulled off as you made me realize i was creating fragments only after clicking tabs. works like a charm now, thank you :)

Comment: also ensure that proper `Tab` is selected "visually" at start (probably diff color and/or some indicator). you may resolve your case easier - just call [selectTab](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout#selectTab(com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.Tab)) passing desired `Tab` right inside `onCreate` but also after setting listener, it should be triggered, thus calling your current code placed only inside listener call